# Paginating my JSON Results

Tags: php, json, api, pagination

Having a little issue getting pagination to work with my API.  This is my current code and it's not working (not displaying any pagination at all):

```
<?php
//functions relating to wordpress go here:
//----------------------------------------
$bg_colors = array('green', 'orange', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'black');
//----------------------------------------
//End functions relating to wordpress

// Start PetRescue PHP/API Code
//----------------------------------------
// Open CuRL/JSON Stuff

$ch = curl_init();
$category=$_GET['category'];
$url="http://www.myapisite.com.au/api/listings?token=f716909f5d644fe3702be5c7895aa34e&group_id=10046&species=".$category;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Accept: application/json',
'X-some-API-Key: f716909f5d644fe3702be5c7895aa34e',
));
$json = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

// Pagination
foreach($json['total_pages'] as $total_pages){
$pagenow=$total_pages['page'];
if($pagenow) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
    else
        $start = 0;

if ($pagenow == 0) $page = 1;
    $prev = $pagenow - 1;
    $next = $pagenow + 1;
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;
    $pagination = "";

if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"ac-pages-wrapper\">";
        if ($pagenow > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$url?page=$prev\">&lt; Previous</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"first\">&lt; Previous</span>"; 

        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $pagenow)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$url?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                    
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            if($pagenow < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))     
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $pagenow)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$url?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                    
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$url?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$url?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";      
            }

            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $pagenow && $pagenow > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$url?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$url?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $pagenow - $adjacents; $counter <= $pagenow + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $pagenow)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }

                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$url?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$url?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";      
            }

            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$url?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$url?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $pagenow)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$url?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                    
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($pagenow < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$url?page=$next\">next �</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">next �</span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
    }


// Functions relating to the Echo Code

foreach($json['listings'] as $listing)
{
$short_personality=substr($listing['personality'],0,500);
$peturl="http://myurl/beta/pet-info/?petid=".$listing['id'];
$medium_photo=$listing['photos'][0]['large_340'];
$gallery_listing=$listing['photos'][5]['large_900'];
$gender_class=strtolower($listing['gender']);
$breed_class=strtolower($listing['species']);
$name=($listing['name']);
$unique_gallery_name="lightbox['.$inc.']";
    $inc++;
foreach($listing["photos"] as $photosthumb)
          {
            $photo_thumb_large=$photosthumb["large_340"];
            $photo_thumb_hidden=$photosthumb["small_80"];
          }
$rand_background = $bg_colors[array_rand($bg_colors)];

// General IF/AND/ELSE Statements to refine the Echo Output
if($listing['photos'] == null) {
    $medium_photo="http://myurl/beta/wp-content/themes/Archive/images/photo_coming_soon.png";
}
if($listing['desexed'] == "Yes") {
    $desexed="yes";
}
else {
    $desexed="no";
}
if($listing['vaccinated'] == "Yes") {
    $vaccinated="yes";
}
else {
    $vaccinated="no";
}
if($listing['wormed'] == "Yes") {
    $wormed="yes";
}
elseif($listing['wormed'] == "No") {
    $wormed="no";
}
else {
    $wormed="no";
}
if($listing['heart_worm_treated'] == "Yes") {
    $heart_worm_tested="yes";
}
elseif($listing['heart_worm_treated'] == "No") {
    $heart_worm_tested="no";
}
else {
    $heart_worm_tested="no";
}
if($listing['species'] == "Dog") {
    $adoption_enquiry_link="http://myurl/beta/pre-adoption-form-dogs/?dog_name=$name";
    $hwt="list-$heart_worm_tested";
}
elseif($listing['species'] == "Cat") {
    $adoption_enquiry_link="http://myurl/beta/pre-adoption-form-cats/?cat_name=$name";
    $hwt="list-hwt-hidden";
}

// Echo the output

echo'<div class="animal">
        <div class="animal-image">
<a class="size-thumbnail thickbox" rel="'.$unique_gallery_name.'" href="'.$medium_photo.'">
                <img src="'.$medium_photo.'" class="image-with-border" alt="">
                <div class="border" style="width: 340px; height: 340px;">
                    <div class="open"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        <div class="item-title-bg '.$rand_background.'">
                <h2 class="entry-title">'.$listing['name'].'</h2>
                <div class="animal-adopt-button">
    <a href="'.$adoption_enquiry_link.'" style="background-color: #575757; border-color: #494949; background-position:5px 0;" class="button medium">Enquire about '.$name.'</a>
                </div>      
            </div>      
        </div>      
        <div class="animal-thumbnail hidden">
<a class="lightbox" rel="'.$unique_gallery_name.'" href="'.$photo_thumb_large.'">
                    <img class="animal-thumbnail" src="'.$photo_thumb_hidden.'" >
                    </a>
        </div>      
<div class="animal-content">
    <div class="animal-left">
        <ul class="animal-list">
            <li class="list-sex-'.$gender_class.'">'.$listing['gender'].'</li>
            <li class="list-breed-'.$breed_class.'">'.$listing['breeds_display'].'</li>
            <li class="list-age">'.$listing['age'].'</li>
            <li class="list-fee">'.$listing['adoption_fee'].'</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div class="animal-right">
        <ul class="animal-list">
            <li class="list-'.$desexed.'">Desexed?</li>
            <li class="list-'.$vaccinated.'">Vaccinated?</li>
            <li class="list-'.$wormed.'">Wormed?</li>
            <li class="'.$hwt.'">Heart Worm Tested?</li>
        </ul>
</div>
<div class="animal-full">
        <ul class="animal-list">
            <li class="list-description">'.$listing['personality'].'</li>
        </ul>
</div></div>
<div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
<div class="delimiter"></div>
<div class="ac-pages-wrapper">'.$pagination.'</div>';
// Close the CURL
}

}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried multiple variations on this, and googled a fair bit, but most of them are to do with MySQL.

I'm using an API to get the data instead of a database and the "page" and "total_pages" are part of the JSON response, so I'm a little unsure how to go about this.

Cheers,

Dave

Comment: Would it be possibe to get a copy of the 'json' array that you used? I can then run your code and have a laff! jokin'! :-) I can then sort out the 'paging' code. You would need to 'var_export' it and put it online so i can get at using one of the 'online clipboards'. I cannot help with the 'cUrl' stuff.

Comment: Here you go Ryan, hope this is what you wanted: http://www.wepaste.com/haart/

Comment: got it, have converted it to an array and it looks sensible as an array. i will play with it later.

Comment: Can you send the css file that you use for this.  i already have a class that i created a while ago that looks after the 'page' selector (start prev 3 4 5 next end). I have code working that displays so many 'listings' per page depending on the page selected. (i am bored with 'Hector'!) I have the 'page selector' array calculated for the current page. I am looking at the HTML generation for the 'page selector' currently.

Comment: btw, if you wish to see the data as a php array that you can include etc. here it is: **[haartphparrray](http://www.wepaste.com/haartphparrray/)**

Comment: Here's the CSS, Ryan: http://www.wepaste.com/haartcss/

Comment: The item display with your css looks good - photos. The low level paging selector is working fine. Having a little bother with the decorator that generates all the URLs and HTML from the page selector. Just sillies. Later. Will post some code tomorrow that shows where we are up to. p.s. thinking of adopting 'Hector' ;-/

Comment: Awesome man.  Thanks.  If you were in WA, then Hector would be all yours! :)  Unfortunately we don't adopt to the UK, but have a few contacts if you're looking for a doggy companion! ;)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I wsn't sure you still wanted it so i took a day off. I would like to sort out the actual listing display which isn't difficult just tedious. I will do that today and post the currnt site and code. We will then be in a position to sort out final details. I am aiming to make the code easy to maintain. If you look at the source for the paging (**pagination.php**) you will see i have explained what to and how to use it. Is that sufficient? I am enjoying it and will use a lot of the code myself.

Comment: Am tidying up the display - alas, got fascinated trying to sort out some useful functions for dealing with photos. Will produce something useful tomorrow. If you have a look at the listing file then you can see what the actual photos that are available and perhaps can decide how you want then displayed. A clear explanation would help. I will do something useful anyway. I already have the website able to change the 'entries per page' via a form. I can also change the number of items displayed in the 'page selector' dynamiclly.

Comment: I should probably mention at this point that I'm using this inside wordpress and will eventually incorporate it into the Plugin that's almost ready.  Shoot me an email dave [at] haart [dot] org [dot] au and i'll send you the link to the dev site.

Answer (score 0):

Second version of an answer 12/4/2012.

There is a website that you can see the paging and display code working:

It allows you to:

```
1) Change the number of items per page
2) Change the number of 'slots' in the page selector.
```

**http://rfv123.eu.pn/pets/**

I have completed the 'paging code'.

You can now adjust the number of 'slots' shown in the 'page selector' code.

I am satisfied with the 'paging' code currently.

The 'pet' display code has been converted to use 'Savant3' templates, which use PHP as the 'template' language. The useful part is that it allows easy separation of 'display' from 'logic' code. While still allowing all the power of PHP available in 'views'. I prefer this.

**[download full code here (zip file)](http://ge.tt/9mm8ehY1/v/0)**

I will be making a separate archive for the 'paging' code as it really is 'stand alone' code. that can be used anywhere.

The paging code is controlled by 'constants', and supplied parameters. The formatting is all css.

The current web-site uses the 'test data' you supplied earlier.

The 'paging code' is free for use by anyone. It is standard stuff that has been re-invented everywhere. Including by me. It uses classes and 'pages' arrays with a fixed number of items per page, when constructed. You can set the 'current page number' and it will return the following:

1) an array of items to be displayed on the page

2) A 'page selector' that has a variable number of 'slots' decorated with HTML.

Comment: This is starting to look awesome. Thanks for the work you're putting into this.  What do you want to do from here?  Keep going on here or work offline?  Apologies for the late reply, was enjoying a rare weekend off! :)